# Package SWF into an EXE or APP

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I am trying to adjust my Flash development workflow so that I am using Flash Builder for all of my coding and multiple FLA files for the user interfaces. I will be creating an ActionScript project in Flash Builder and then having each FLA export a SWC into a resources folder.

It is important that I retain the ability to export PC and Mac -- EXE and app, respectively -- projector files. Is there a way of doing this with the Flash compiler or any 3rd party tools?

I know that mProjector and similar tools can do this, but I would like a solution that can be automated into my builds.

EDIT 5/14/2010 9:30 AM: One of my options is to use AIR, however...Flash Builder does not let you build an AIR application from an ActionScript project. Another option is to use Zinc...does Zinc have any command line options such that I can include that in my build process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different options available:

- Use AIR
- Encapsulate your completed project in a fla (setting the document's class to your custom class) and then publish it as win/mac projector
- Use a third-party application to convert swf to native executables. The best known option there is probably [zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/)

Comment: After looking around for a while, I'm just sticking with using FLAs.

Answer (score 2):

and really, You can pack everything into exe. For example, using flajector can convert the file into exe. and you will not need to think about ... was Flash player installed or not...application will be available in any case

Comment: +1 also you can use f-in-box - powerful developer's library to enhance Flash Player ActiveX features.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a look at [zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/). also, if the machines you want to run on have [AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) installed, you may simply wanna build an AIR app.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an AIR application from a pure ActionScript project. Apparently it's not as obvious as it should be, but here's one way of doing it:

http://ted.onflash.org/2010/03/air-apps-using-actionscript-only.php

Also the very latest version of AIR (currently in RC stage, so stable enough to use, final version will be released soon) can package the app into an EXE so you don't need to install the AIR framework separately.

AIR packages can also be compiled from the commandline, so should be easy to integrate into a separate build process if you don't want to do it from the Flash Builder GUI.

Answer (score 0):

**Turning SWF into an iOS App/OS App via Xcode and Zinc 4.0 (will help Windows users part of the way)**

**Step 1**:Be an iOS Developer with Working XCode, Provisioning Profile, etc.

**Step 1**: Download Zinc and Install it

**Step 2**: Using Zinc select to start a new project and pick the .swf file you want to turn into an app

**Step 3**: Build / Compile the app - this will create a .app and a .exe file if you select to build for all platforms when compiling

If you are a windows developer then this is as far as you go. Enjoy! If you are a mac/ios dev then continue on.

**Step 4**: Select your new projector file (.app) and click to 'Convert Projector into an XCode project under the 'Project' tab up top

*NOTE -  For anyone looking for their projector (or .app file on a mac) made by Zinc 4.0+ to turn into an XCode project, you may have to look in your file directory around the .swf file you used to build the projector in the first place. At first I was frustrated for a bit since I (the Finder on my mac) can easily find the new .exe file but it could not see the .app file with search*

**Step 5**: Locate your new XCode project folder (in the same general place and with same name as your .app) and drag it into XCode

**Step 7**: Make sure your scheme is correct (Mac OSX or iOS), if it is not then go to build settings and go to 'Base SDK' and switch it to the correct one

**Step 8**: Check your provisioning, (while still in Build Settings) and select the right code signing and provisioning profile for your app, check your bundle id to make sure it will work too, if you get a problem with code signing after this and you are sure your profile is correct then put

```
--deep
```

in the 'Other Code Signing Flags' section

*Note - My app was set up to be a mac app and so it had some #import  calls that I had to remove and remove the reference to the Cocoa framework on the general section, and put in calls to  and  instead*

**Step 9**: Archive the app to make the .ipa file and submit it to the app store/post it for ad hoc purposes/build it on a dev device

*Note - If submitting to the app store/testflight you may want to look at your .ipa file after this whole process, normally an .ipa is just a fancy zip with a 'Payload' folder that contains your app (with a big cancel symbol over the icon) if after decompresing your ipa (after renaming the .ipa to .zip) you see that your top folder is not called Payload or that your app is actually contained in several folders, then make a new folder called 'Payload' move the icon with the cancel sign on it to the new folder and compress it into a .zip then rename the .zip into a .ipa and you should be good to upload the the app store or testflight*